# OpenGL support for integrated intel 82865G on Vista

Tags: windows-vista, drivers, graphics-card, opengl

I am looking to run an app that requires OpenGL drivers (XBMC).  I have a old Dell Dimension 4600 with the intel integrated graphics chip - 82865G and running Vista.  The Microsoft drivers do not support OpenGL, the intel drivers with OpenGL support were last updated in 2005, and do not have Vista Support. (http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Product_Filter.aspx?ProductID=1044) The XP drivers will not install.  Dell's website has drivers as well, but no Vista support.

Is there any way to get OpenGL support with my machine while running Vista?  If not, guess I will need to get a real video card for this machine.

Answer (score 1):

A google search for that chipset got me to here -

http://majorgeeks.com/Intel_Chipset_Software_Installation_Utility_d1667.html .

Dated 2009-07-15. Give it a go and see how you get on.

Comment: installed this, but the chipset drivers included in this Intel Updater are the same ones. Still no Open GL Support